# Refresh Token Lifetime and Revoking

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am working on a Google Drive App.

What is the lifetime of a Refresh Token? I have read that it lasts till until it is revoked. However, I also read somewhere that if your app is not used for 60 days, then the refresh token expires. Is this true ?
Also, who revokes the refresh token, is it the the user or in my case Google itself after a certain period of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not heard of a refresh token expiring after 60 days inactivity. Do you have a link that claims so?

The token can be revoke by the user or by your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think, as per my study for the google drive file access using the refresh_token. The refresh token stays for around 6 months and then it we have to revoke it at that time when it gets expired. Google api's documents are nice and easy bit somehow lacks the way to use it.Just a thought, and once stuck got to search many place and less response to issues.